# Android Jellybean Activity Lifecycle Bug

Tags: java, android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, activity-lifecycle

My problem only occurs when I lock the screen and only in Jellybean 4.1.2 and 4.2.2. Tested on a Galaxy mini and an HTC. Both cyanogen mod. The problem is when I lock it it's call onPause then onResume then onPause again. And when I unlock it it doesn't call any events. Whenener I press the home and navigate back it behaves normal. I have also tested on 2.3.5 (Gingerbread) it worked perfectly. How is this possible?

I think that's an error in the android os or the rom but I also think it's possible to find a work around.

Please send me an answer if you can.

```
03-04 20:14:30.844: D/dalvikvm(24688): Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-04 20:14:30.994: E/Trace(24688): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-04 20:14:31.404: D/libEGL(24688): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
03-04 20:14:31.414: D/libEGL(24688): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-04 20:14:31.414: D/libEGL(24688): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-04 20:14:31.424: I/Adreno200-EGL(24688): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:294>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.036_msm8960_JB_CL2644550_release_AU (CL2644550)
03-04 20:14:31.424: I/Adreno200-EGL(24688): Build Date: 07/31/12 Tue
03-04 20:14:31.424: I/Adreno200-EGL(24688): Local Branch: 
03-04 20:14:31.424: I/Adreno200-EGL(24688): Remote Branch: quic/master
03-04 20:14:31.424: I/Adreno200-EGL(24688): Local Patches: NONE
03-04 20:14:31.424: I/Adreno200-EGL(24688): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.036 +  NOTHING
03-04 20:14:31.464: D/OpenGLRenderer(24688): Enabling debug mode 0 <- ENTERED THE APP
03-04 20:14:33.564: D/Weird Error(24688): Resumed
03-04 20:14:33.714: D/Weird Error(24688): Created
03-04 20:14:43.044: D/Weird Error(24688): Paused <- LOCKED THE SCREEN
03-04 20:14:43.244: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24688): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-04 20:14:43.244: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24688): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
03-04 20:14:43.394: D/Weird Error(24688): Resumed
03-04 20:14:43.394: D/Weird Error(24688): Paused
03-04 20:16:31.294: I/dalvikvm(24688): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-04 20:16:31.344: I/dalvikvm(24688): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-04 20:16:38.054: E/Trace(24767): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-04 20:16:38.384: D/libEGL(24767): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so <- I GUESS UNLOCKED IT BUT NOTHING PROVES IT
03-04 20:16:38.384: D/libEGL(24767): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
03-04 20:16:38.394: D/libEGL(24767): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
03-04 20:16:38.394: I/Adreno200-EGL(24767): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:294>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.036_msm8960_JB_CL2644550_release_AU (CL2644550)
03-04 20:16:38.394: I/Adreno200-EGL(24767): Build Date: 07/31/12 Tue
03-04 20:16:38.394: I/Adreno200-EGL(24767): Local Branch: 
03-04 20:16:38.394: I/Adreno200-EGL(24767): Remote Branch: quic/master
03-04 20:16:38.394: I/Adreno200-EGL(24767): Local Patches: NONE
03-04 20:16:38.394: I/Adreno200-EGL(24767): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB.04.01.01.00.036 +  NOTHING
03-04 20:16:38.434: D/OpenGLRenderer(24767): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Comment: post your logcat output please.

Comment: my logcat test or the logcat at all?

Comment: all of it so we can see what is occurring.

Comment: Would you annotate the LogCat so we know when you did what actions?

Comment: annonated with <- CAPITAL TEXT

Comment: I've had the same problem today. I think I had something in my onResume that made the activity finish. Haven't seen the issue again after I've fixed by own bugs, so I haven't investigated the problem much more. I'll have a look again tomorrow at work to see if the onPause is called again, but I guess not because the app works. 
Double check your code in onresume

Comment: I'm still pretty new to Android and at this point someone else with more experience may need to see this to figure it out, but from what I can see the only thing that is occurring once you pause it, besides onResume & onPause again, is that IInputConnectionWrapper: begin/endBatchEdit. This seems odd to me and I wonder if that could be causing your problem.

Comment: So you think input causes the problem? I have only a single touch and a n accelerometer input controller.

Comment: The only code in on resume is:

glView.onResume();
super.onResume();

And it calls even when it's not supposed to. I think GL crashes the app beacuse it call when the screen is actually off.

Comment: You may find some answers in this link:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/making-android-games-that-play-nice.html

Comment: I've just read the blog and it says I should use user input to resume the game. But how if the opengl shows a freezed black screen after unlock? But I will keep the pause input in mind.

Comment: @thibaultd You said you have or had the same problem. Was it with a custom or just a jellybean rom?

Comment: @DanielSharp the one that comes with my Samsung Galaxy SII

Comment: Somehow I can't re-create the bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

I changed this:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to this:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

I'll leave the question so others experience the same problem may find an answer.